# Execute the sqlite3 connector with golang in vscode. Met below error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: go, go-sqlite3

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Users struct {
    UserId, intUname string
}

func main() {
    os.Remove("foo.db")

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "foo.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    sql := `create table users (userId integer, uname text);`
    db.Exec(sql)
    sql = `insert into users(userId,uname) values(1,'Mike');`
    db.Exec(sql)
    sql = `insert into users(userId,uname) values(2,'John');`
    db.Exec(sql)
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from users")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var users []Users = make([]Users, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        var u Users
        rows.Scan(&u.UserId, &u.intUname)
        users = append(users, u)
    }
    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

Above is my codes. Now I will run this file. Codes only connect to sqlite3 database, And execute some sql, No any else operate. I don't know why to happen this.

**Met below error:**

csccl25013> go run .

## github.com/goproject/sqlite3

/nfs/site/disks/simcloud_zhoudo1x_002/go/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/nfs/site/itools/em64t_SLES12SP5/pkgs/gcc/4.7.2/.bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-322571714/000015.o(.text+0x63): unresolvable AWAVAUATUSH��h�*H�T$(���� relocation against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/nfs/site/itools/em64t_SLES12SP5/pkgs/gcc/4.7.2/.bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**I don't know how to resolve this error. Please help me.**

**Expected Result:**

Execute successful.

Connect sqlite3 normally.

Comment: It appears your C compiler isn't set up correctly. Please add the output from `go env` to your question - it may help.

Comment: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#cross-compile use `go build --tags "linux"`

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates your Go toolchain is unable to build the CGO implementation for `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` (eg, cross-compilation error).

If you are unable to troubleshoot your C compiler you could try importing `modernc.org/sqlite` and using the `"sqlite"` SQL driver instead. This is a pure Go conversion of Sqlite and avoids the need for the C compiler.

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot. After I replace the sqlite driver to modernc.org/sqlite, Those codes can run well.   We can use this command to download: go get modernc.org/sqlite.    We can refer to below documents:https://pkg.go.dev/modernc.org/sqlite#section-readme